# Hiding elements in my wordpress blog

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to take out of each post this section "/ No Comment / Read More » / Edit" or hide if you will. this is the website www.justsaynews.com

how do I do this?

Comment: Seeing as the links have no CSS class that could be used to target them in the style sheet, I would edit the template and comment out the links manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing would be to edit the template as Pekka has pointed out.

However I think it is possible by quickly looking at the source to hide it using CSS.

To remove only the links 'No comment' and 'Read more':

```
span.featuredPostMeta a { display: none; }
```

or to remove the entire block including the date:

```
span.featuredPostMeta { display: none; }
```

However please test it to see whether other data gets hidden or not.